# Is it possible to use flexbox order in two different sections?

Tags: html, css

I have a page designed like this:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="div1">A</div>
    <div class="div1">B</div>
    <div class="div1">C</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="div2">D</div>
    <div class="div2">E</div>
    <div class="div2">F</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

I am applying responsiveness. I would like to know if it is possible to use **only css** to organize the `divs` this:

[image: Reorder]

Comment: no, not if the divs are organized in sections like in your code

Comment: You can use grid layout without the sections, otherwise you would need to use javascript to achieve it...

Comment: I got it, this seems to be the best solution, I will do it.

Comment: It would be a bit hacky but you ***could*** make your `main section` `position: relative;`, then make each div container `position: absolute;` and then position the elements statically using the `left` and `top` positions...

Comment: So your *div 4* or `D` div would have a *top* of `0` *left position* equal to the `width of your divs` + any margin/padding... then `B` div would be left 0 and top *height of your divs* and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see to achieve the layout with a `<section>` tag present separating each `div1` and `div2` would be to use positioning each child elements left and top positions relative to the parent. It is very static and likely has a high potential of breaking with content and scrolling, etc...

***Not recommended...*** see the hidden snippit below to see that working

```css
.main section {
  position: relative;
}

.one {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.four {
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
  top: 0;
}

.two {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 55px;
}

.three {
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
  top: 55px;
}

.five {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 110px;
  width: 210%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.six {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 165px;
  width: 210%;
  overflow: auto;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section>
    <div class="div1 one">1</div>
    <div class="div1 two">2</div>
    <div class="div1 three">3</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="div2 four">4</div>
    <div class="div2 five">5</div>
    <div class="div2 six">6</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

A more cohesive approach would be to get rid of the `<section>` tags and use a [grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)...

You still have the classes **div1** and **div2** for alternate styling. Using the grid layout you can create a `grid-template-area` using the `grid-area` on individual class names for each element.

While you still have your child elements laid out incrementally *one, two, three, four, etc...* You can move a child element anywhere in the grid pattern using the `grid-template-area` calling on the elements `grid-area` value.

In the following example, each div has a class representing its position in the original layout, `one`, `two`, `three`, etc...
Note the **column** and **row** `fr` units... very literal in its approach. Visualize ***two*** *columns* each separated equally per column, then ***four*** *rows*, each separated equally per row, then we add the elements with the `grid-template-area`...

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-area:
  "one four" 
  "two three" 
  "five five" 
  "six six";
}
```

```css
html {
  --width: 100%;
  --height: 100%;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px 2px;
  grid-template-areas: "one four" "two three" "five five" "six six";
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
}

.five {
  grid-area: five;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
}

.six {
  grid-area: six;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
}

.div1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="div1 one box">A</div>
    <div class="div1 two box">B</div>
    <div class="div1 three box">C</div>
    <div class="div2 four box">D</div>
    <div class="div2 five box">E</div>
    <div class="div2 six box">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For sure the best solution is the second one you described. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

yes you could by using orders like this .div1 {order: __}